Getting error after changing spring-boot version to 3.4.0 from 3.1.4
There was an error in the forked process
Cannot instantiate class xxxxx.api.controller.AdminControllerTest
Standard Commons Logging discovery in action with spring-jcl: please remove commons-logging.jar from classpath in order to avoid potential conflicts
[ERROR]
Cannot instantiate class xxxxx.api.controller.AdminControllerTest
I am blank with it, what can be the possible issue and How can I resolve it. Please help me with it

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
